# Exercise Package: What is the correct way to custom exercise and question header

Tags: exercises

I'm trying to typeset exercise with custom style, basically like this:

```
Exercise 1.1 [**] Some background.
1. First question.
2.[***] Then the second with different difficulty.
```

I've tried to `\renewcommand` and `\def` as manual suggests, however:

1. I can't find one and also manual says there's no one definition for `\questionHeader`,
2. To place the difficulty marker after number, I have to `\renewcommand` every level of exercise, is that what I should do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.